# Telephony package listener not working in background

Tags: flutter, dart, telephony

I have a problem with the [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony) package for listening to incoming SMS messages in the background.
in my app, I want to listen to retrieving SMS when the app is in the background but the listener does not work. I used the [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package for background service. I did some debug tests and the background service has no problem.
here is my code:

```
backgrounMessageHandler(SmsMessage message) async {
  print(message.body);
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
callBackDispacher() {
  bg.Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    Telephony telephony = Telephony.backgroundInstance;
    await telephony.requestSmsPermissions;
    telephony.listenIncomingSms(
        onNewMessage: backgrounMessageHandler,
        onBackgroundMessage: backgrounMessageHandler);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await bg.Workmanager().initialize(callBackDispacher, isInDebugMode: true);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: What's your purpose for listening SMS, Do you try to read an OTP from a message?

Comment: @JenisNavadiya no I want to pop a notification after receiving SMS. for this I need the body of the message.

Comment: @ParhamKhoshravesh have you added the permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml?  Instructions for doing so are under the section marked "Listen to Incoming SMS" at the link you provided.  https://shounakmulay.gitbook.io/telephony/listen-incoming-sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change or add a git link in pubspec.yaml,

```
telephony: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definev/Telephony.git
      ref: develop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.   In the question, they already have access to the library.

This is how you add it to a pubspec.yaml:

dependencies:
  telephony: ^0.2.0

The git link you recommended will not load the public version from pub,dev, but rather load a fork from a github user named definev.